# How to get the size of span of longest word in dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Apz9e/8/

there is a dropdown. the problem is that the label of dropdown change the size upon the length of selected option.

by jquery I want to set the width always matching to longest item in list.

Please make your edit here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Apz9e/8/

[image]

#### HTML

```
   <form method="post" action=""> 

<div>
            <select class="select" title="Select one">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option>Blue</option>
                <option >Red</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>
                <option>Brown</option>
            </select>
        </div>

</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

    if (!$.browser.opera) {

        // select element styling
        $('select.select').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            if( $('option:selected', this).val() != ''  ) title = $('option:selected',this).text();
            $(this)
                .css({'z-index':10,'opacity':0,'-khtml-appearance':'none'})
                .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
                .change(function(){
                    val = $('option:selected',this).text();
                    $(this).next().text(val);
                    })
        });

    };

});
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:40px 40px;
    background:#fff;

    color:#555;
    line-height:180%;
}

/* all form DIVs have position property set to relative so we can easily position newly created SPAN */
form div {position:relative;


} 

/* setting the width and height of the SELECT element to match the replacing graphics */
span.select, select.select {

width:auto ;
        height:auto ;
    font:3.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
   padding:1% 1%
}


select.select{
        position:relative;
        z-index:10;

        line-height:1;
         padding:0 0.5%
}

select option {padding-top:3px; border-bottom:1px solid red}

/* dynamically created SPAN, placed below the SELECT */
span.select{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    float:left;
    left:2px;
    line-height:1;
    text-indent:10px
     background: #ffffff;
background: url('images/color-arrow.png') no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #a9a9a9 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#a9a9a9));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#a9a9a9 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#a9a9a9 100%);
    cursor:default;
    z-index:1; 
    border:#dadada 1px solid; 
    border-radius:6px;    
    background-position: 100% center; 
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #fff; 

    }
```

Comment: hey @alex why did you remove your answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make the select box and set it to the width of one of the option

```
var sel=//get select element
sel.style.width=$('select>option').clientWidth+'px';
```

I'm not sure of the exact jquery syntax but this should give you the idea.  Also this does not take into consideration margins, so you might need to adjust for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using .each to run through option to get outerWidth and then comparing against a set minimum and then subtracting 10 for your text-indent:

http://jsfiddle.net/Apz9e/13/

Comment: Hmmm.. I just found [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7093).  Maybe it is because in the fiddle the css is loading after the js ?